# Generic type class instances performance

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a type class

```
trait CanMeow[T] {
    def meow(t:T):String
}
```

Now I have a different type class

```
trait IsCatEquivalent[T] {
    def makeSound(t:T):String
    def isAlive(t:T):Boolean
}
```

And now I want to make every CatEquivalent member of CanMeow type class. What I can do is

```
implicit def catEquivalentCanMeow[T](implicit ce:IsCatEquivalent[T]) = new CanMeow[T] {
    def meow(t:T) = ce.makeSound(t)
}
```

How does this affect performance? From the looks of it every time a method is called with implicit parameter of type CanMeow[T] a new object is constructed. Is it so? And if, is this cheap enough that it is not worth caching the instances?

Other question: is there a better way to do this? (Making one type class extend the other may not be an option, for example if they come from different libraries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare the performance impact of implicit conversion and its alternatives, see [this article](http://villane.wordpress.com/2008/02/02/learning-scala-performance-impact-of-implicit-conversions/). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381940/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-scala-implicit-type-conversions) contains another microbenchmark.

Comment: Thanks, It should have occurred to me to look for implicit conversions.